# ¿Porque no me valida el model en el método crear?

Tags: c#, .net, mvc, model-view-controller

Luego de tener los modelos y el context listo estoy usando scaffolding para crear los controladores y las vistas. Luego de tener las vistas y los controladores creados hago pruebas con el create y el edit pero no me crea ni me edita. Le estoy haciendo seguimiento al código y cuando entra al if del create donde está validando si el modelo es válido este salta directamente y se sale de la ejecución, no sé por qué sucede, pero cuando quito la colección de matrículas ahí si me deja crear sin problema

este es el código de crear del modelo del controlador

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Create([Bind("Id,Nombre,Descripcion")] Curso curso)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        curso.Id = Guid.NewGuid();
        _context.Add(curso);
        await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
        return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
    }
    return View(curso);
}
```

este es el modelo de curso

```
publicclassCurso
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Nombre { get; set; }
    public string Descripcion { get; set; }
  
    publicvirtual ICollection<Matricula> Matriculas { get; set; }
}
```

este es el modelo de matriculas

```
publicclassMatricula
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public DateTime Fecha { get; set; }
    public Guid EstudianteId { get; set; }
    public Guid CursoId { get; set; }
    public Guid DocenteId { get; set; }

    publicvirtual Estudiante Estudiante { get; set; }
    publicvirtual Curso Curso { get; set; }
    publicvirtual Docente Docente { get; set; }
}
```

primero ingreso a la vista para ingresar la información

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

cuando presiono en el botón create pasa esto

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

el campo colección de matrículas se ingresa como null, y al no poder ser null no entra en el if y no crea el nuevo curso

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

Logre resolverlo creando el contructor y enviando una colección vacia

```
public class Curso
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Nombre { get; set; }
    public string Descripcion { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Matricula> Matriculas { get; set; }

    public Curso()
    {
        Matriculas = new Collection<Matricula>();
    }
}
```